# vertical string to horizontal

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hi I know how to print `ONKAR` to

```
O
N
K
A
R
```

but I want to do reverse. I mean

```
O
N
K
A
R
```

to `ONKAR`

Can anyone of you please tell me the query for the same.

Comment: is this a column in table, you should write in more details

Comment: I think you're going to need another column which provides the ordering for the letters in `ONKAR`.

Comment: Database does not store rows in any particular order and the order of the output cannot be determined unless you specify an `order by`. Hence we always keep an id column to uniquely identify the rows. If this was indeed asked  in an interview(from your comment), then the interviewer  does not fully understand fundamental RDBMS principles and is only coming up with a superficial question to amuse him/herself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had better using Oracle's pseudocolumn `Rowid` for providing the proper order of the letters :

```
create table tab( col0 varchar2(50) );
insert all
       into tab values( 'O' )
       into tab values( 'N' )
       into tab values( 'K' )
       into tab values( 'A' )
       into tab values( 'R' )
select * from dual;    

SELECT listagg(col0) within group (order by rd) "My Name is "
  FROM
  (
   SELECT col0, rowid rd
     FROM tab a
    ORDER BY rowid
  );
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c393d4/2)

P.S. Even if rowid doesn't guarantee an order for the columns of tables those getting DML as Kaushik stated, I suggested using `rowid` not to hardcode with an other auxiliary column for such special case.

Comment: No, `ROIWD` does not always guarantee an order. If we delete a letter say 'K' and then re-insert it the order will be lost. Although it works for this case, it is not something which is reliable for ordering in general and there should always be a primary key/id  in any practical scenario.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I agree with you Kaushik that rowid doesn't guarantee, one of the reasons always we're struggling with `row_number()` or `dense_rank()` functions :) but for this special case I suggested as you already mentioned. I didn't want to hardcode with an auxiliary column.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this: this will give you string aggregation

```
    select listagg(column1) within group(order by rn) from
(SELECT column1,row_number() over(partition by column1) as rn
    FROM   table)a
```

Comment: Rather not. `WM_CONCAT` is undocumented and unsupported; moreover, it has been removed from 12c which will break all your programs that use it, once you upgrade to 12c. `LISTAGG` should be used instead.

Comment: In addition, the order in which the letters might appear would probably not be correct.

Comment: Actually this question was asked in interview. "How to print vertical string to horizontal " and they told me the same string to convert.

Comment: @fa06 Hi, I have only one column in table

Comment: chk the answer, you need to create an extra column virtually using rownum and then apply string aggregation on this, hopefully it will give you right ans

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LISTAGG` for this.

Sample :

```
with cte as ( 
    select 1 as pk,'O' AS name from dual
    union all 
    select 2,'N' from dual
    union all 
    select 3,'K' from dual
    union all 
    select 4,'A' from dual
    union all 
    select 5,'R' from dual)
select LISTAGG(name) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY pk) from cte
```

**Edit** : As the others are already mentioned in comments, it will never be possible without a ordering-key column, because there is no way to get those rows out in the order they got inserted.
If you add a dynamic row-number, the best you can get is `ANKOR`or `ROKNA` as there is no rule written in table how the rows should fetch.